# delete procedure not call in sqldataadapter.Deletecommand in mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sqldataadapter

i creat an accounting application in mvc3. i have journal voucher form in it.in this form master and detail data is on single view.i use html table and text boxes in html table for create my grid.I saved my data into sql server 2008 r2 database in 2 tables with help of json and wcf services on single button click.(means on save button click all the master and detail data is inserted in database.there is no edit button on each grid line for editing data into database. 
Now I want to perform my form's edit functionality on single button click into database. 
for this purpose i have an idea that i use sqltransaction object and delete data from database temporarily and then insert new data into database and then do the sqltran.commit or sqltrans.rollback on sucess/fail base of transaction.
for this purpose i create a function in DAL in which it firstly bind sqltransaction with command and then do delete functionality with dataadapter and stored procedure.
**but my stored procedure is not called and data is not delete i monitor it in sql server profiler.

I paste my code here plzzz any one tell me where i do mistake.**

```
public bool JVInsertDAL1(JVEntity Obj, bool FMode, bool EMode, bool DMode)
    {

        bool FinRes = false;
        DataSet ObjDs = new DataSet();
        //function call to fill tables scheme in dataset

        ObjDs = FillDSDAL(ObjDs, "", "");
        if (FMode == false && DMode == true)
        {

            ObjDs = FillDSDAL(ObjDs, Obj.VNo, Obj.Type);
        }
                //==============================

        ///*********MASTER DATA INSERTION************************
        if (EMode != true || DMode != false)
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
            sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
        }
      try
        {

            if (FMode == false && DMode == true)
            {

SqlCommand cmdDeleteLedg = new SqlCommand("SpGLdelete", sqlConnection, sqlTransaction);
cmdDeleteLedg.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlCommand cmdDeleteHead = new SqlCommand("SpGlHeadDelete", sqlConnection, sqlTransaction);
cmdDeleteHead.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmdDeleteHead.Parameters.Add("@VNo", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "VNo").Value = Obj.VNo;
cmdDeleteHead.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "Type").Value=Obj.Type;

cmdDeleteLedg.Parameters.Add("@VNo", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "VNo").Value = Obj.VNo;
cmdDeleteLedg.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "Type").Value = Obj.Type;
 //-----------------PROCEDURE FOR DELETE RECORD DURING EDIT MODE-------------           
                ObjDadp.DeleteCommand = cmdDeleteLedg;
                ObjDadp.Update(ObjDs, "Gledg");

                ObjDadp.DeleteCommand = cmdDeleteHead;
                ObjDadp.Update(ObjDs, "Glhead");

                ObjDs.AcceptChanges();
                ObjDs.Clear();
            }
            if (FMode == true)
            {

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SPJVHeadInsert", sqlConnection, sqlTransaction);
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("SPJVLedgInsert", sqlConnection, sqlTransaction);
sqlCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "Type");
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@VNo", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "VNo");
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@VDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 10, "VDate");

sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "Type");
sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@VNo", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "VNo");
sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@VDate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 10, "VDate");
sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "Code");
         ObjRow = ObjDs.Tables["GlHead"].NewRow();
                    ObjRow["Type"] = Obj.Type;
                    ObjRow["VNo"] = Obj.VNo;
                    ObjRow["VDate"] = Obj.VDate;
                    ObjRow["RefRemarks"] = Obj.RefRemarks;
                    ObjDs.Tables["GlHead"].Rows.Add(ObjRow); 

                    foreach (var trans in Obj.GLedg)
                    {
                        ObjRow = ObjDs.Tables["Gledg"].NewRow();
                        ObjRow["Type"] = trans.Type;
                        ObjRow["VNo"] = trans.VNo;
                        ObjRow["VDate"] = trans.VDate;
                        ObjRow["Code"] = trans.Code;
                        ObjDs.Tables["Gledg"].Rows.Add(ObjRow); 
                    }

                //----------------------------------------------------
            ObjDadp.InsertCommand = sqlCommand;
            ObjDadp.Update(ObjDs, "GlHead");

            ObjDadp.InsertCommand = sqlCommand1;
            ObjDadp.Update(ObjDs, "GLedg");
                //----------------------------------------------------

            }//END OF FMODE=TRUE CONDITION
            //------------------------------------------------------ 

            //****************************************               
            if (DMode != true || EMode != true)
          //  if (EMode != true || DMode != false)
            {
                sqlTransaction.Commit();
            }
            //************************************
        }//end of try
        catch (SqlException sqlError)
        {
            sqlTransaction.Rollback();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sqlTransaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (EMode != true || DMode != true)
            {
                if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
 {
 sqlConnection.Close();
 }
 }
 }            
 //******end of detail insertion***************************************************
 if (FMode == false && DMode == true)
 {
 if (ObjDs.HasErrors== false)
 {
 FinRes = true;
 }
 else
 {
 FinRes = false;
 }
 }
 if (FMode == true)
 {
 if (ObjDs.HasErrors == false)
{
FinRes = true;
}
else
{
FinRes = false;
}
}            
return FinRes;
}
```

In above code i pass FMode: true, EMode: false, DMode: **false for save data and it insert data into database.**
FMode: false, EMode: true, DMode: true **when delete data from database in editing mode.**
and finally FMode: true, EMode: true, DMode: false **for insert data after deletion from database in editing mode.**

Any suggestions for solve my problem?

Comment: Keep in mind that the commands attached to a DataAdapter are executd only if there are changes in the DataTable to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code above it seems that you don't change the contents of the tables `Glhead` and `Gledg`.

Calling the [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx) method of the SqlDataAdapter when the rows of the mentioned tables are all in the state DataRowState.Unchanged result in no action on the database.

> When an application calls the Update method, the DbDataAdapter
>   examines the RowState property, and executes the required INSERT,
>   UPDATE, or DELETE statements iteratively for each row, based on the
>   order of the indexes configured in the DataSet.

You need to delete the row from the datatable and then call the Update method of the SqlDataAdapter